# Order of execution

Tags: force.com

Can someone clarify the following statement from the Order of Execution online documentation.

> The refiring of triggers isn't limited to updates, but applies to all
>   operation types. A workflow field update that fires on record insert
>   will rerun any before and after insert triggers again—as insert
>   triggers.

Does it really mean that insert trigger fires 2nd time ever or it is just a documentation bug?

Link to the documentation v44.0
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

UPDATE: In addition to Workflow field update, update triggers are executed for assignment rules as well, but why it is not mentioned in the documentation clearly that update triggers will run once more due to assignment rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After finding a bug in my original code/answer, I have confirmed that the documentation is wrong. The workflow field update will trigger update triggers instead of insert triggers. This probably needs to reported to the documentation team.

Comment: Hi @Sfdcfox, thank you for the update. I updated my original question for assignment rules as well. Just wondering why that was not mentioned in the documentation. Based on this discussion it seems that platform treat them as workflow internally,  is it correct?

Comment: @LakhanP Yes, it shows up as a workflow field update and will trigger update triggers as well.

Comment: that doc bug showed up in V43.0; the yellow highlighted area was not present in V42.0 doc

Comment: @cropredy Sounds about right. I have reported this to the docs team.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments/clarifications on this.

Comment: @sfdcfox, just came across this post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263030/issue-with-insert-trigger-after-workflow-field-update.  I am thinking if that is really a documentation bug then why it has not be fixed in 2 years (after almost 6 releases). If its not a bug, did you came across a scenario where that can happen?

Comment: @LakhanP Not sure, but I just tested the code/config from this question, and it still behaves now as it did then. I have logs I can share that proves the behavior. Perhaps there's an allOrNone=false operation? If the Id is changing, it's not the same record, whatever's happening.

Comment: Same here, I also tried many scenarios but unable to replicate re-run of insert triggers. Let me raise a case with Salesforce, if they can update the documentation so that to avoid confusion.

Comment: @sfdcfox I had raised a case with SFDC, they have created a defect (#W-5650660) for this and expectation to close this is within one or two weeks.

Comment: @LakhanP Thanks for following up!